# Cut the string in half with the last specific character shows up in the string

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

For example, with the string `a_link_list_java`, use the `_` character to separate the string in half would result in: `a_link_list` and `java`.

`list_java` would result in: `list` and `java`.

I want to take these two parts and store them into two variables.

I tried the `cut` command but it only works for only one character shown in the string

How can I accomplish this in a bash shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell's [parameter expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) can do that:

```
$ v="a_link_list_java"
$ printf "%s\n" "${v%_*}" "${v##*_}"
a_link_list
java
```

Though note that if the patterns in the expansion don't match, nothing is removed. So a value without an underscore would be unchanged by both transformations:

```
$ v=foo
$ printf "%s\n" "${v%_*}" "${v##*_}"
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can have all in separate defining delimiter as `_`

```
VAR1=$(awk -F'_' '{print $1}' infile.txt)
```

You can print which fields you want based on its index above instead of `$1` that points to first field.

Or you can use `bash` and read as an array.

```
IFS='_' read -r -a array <<< "$myString"
```

then simply read with individual index number:

```
echo "${array[2]}"
```

Or even simply you can use bash parameter expansion:

```
VAR1="${myString%_*}"   # will gives you 'a_link_list' 
VAR2="${myString##*_}"  # will gives you 'java' 
VAR3="${VAR1%_*}"       # will gives you 'a_link'
```

Comment: for example a_link_list_java  , i want my first field to be a_link_list , not a, Because I do not know about how many '_' would contain in the string

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
var1=$(sed 's/_[^_]*$//' file)
var2=$(sed 's/.*_//' file)
```

Notice that `sed` is very greedy, so in the second case glob `*` swallows all characters, including previous underscores `_`.

Output:

```
$ echo "$var1"
a_link_list
$ echo "$var2"
java
```